# How detect Device from this User Agent?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, user-agent, browscap

I have user agent list from browscap to detect Device, Browser, Brand, and more. I'm already import to database, but now I'm get some problem to run because user agent format like this.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (*Windows NT 10.0*Win64? x64*) AppleWebKit/* (KHTML* like Gecko) Chrome/56.*Safari/*
```

And I'm checking my user agent using HTTP_USER_AGENT showing this

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

Browscap user agent have string `*`

Can I'm run using WHERE or WHERE LIKE in SQL?
I'm already try with WHERE LIKE %% but not working correctly

**UPDATE** :
I'm already try with simple PHP code like this and also not working

```
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
echo $ua;

 $perintah = "SELECT * FROM useragent WHERE PropertyName = '".$ua."'";
 $hasil = mysqli_query($con,$perintah);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($hasil)){

 echo $row['id'];

 }
```

Please give me solution to resolve this problem. Thank You.

Comment: Show the actual code you are using. I have no idea what you currently are doing that fails.

Comment: I was still thinking about how to implement the code for that user agent :(

Comment: `but not working correctly` if you don't have something how can it "not work"?

Comment: I just try only with SQL query.. Please wait until I'm updating some code in my question

Comment: @chris85 I'm updating my question

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put arbitrary user data like `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Code I'm showing just for using a tester only @tadman

Comment: Writing it correctly saves you the horror of this code ending up in production. It should be a disciplined habit.

Comment: Yeah, You have solutions to make my Code working? @tadman

Comment: The problem here is not the asterisks, it's that you can't exact match these things. Split that up into meaningful tokens and try a different approach. As a note, discerning anything useful out of these strings is really frustrating. For reasons that I cannot begin to explain everyone masquerades as "Mozilla/5.0" and then Chrome pretends to be Safari pretending to be Mozilla and sometimes IE pretends to be Chrome pretending to be Safari pretending to be Mozilla... These days I treat everything in here as a complete fabrication and not to be trusted.